# I started a simple image processing project, I want to connect the license plate of the car to the graphical environment .How should I do this?

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, pyqt5

**> I don't know how to use graphical library with Code**

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
import imutils
import pytesseract as tess
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QWidget, QPushButton, QLineEdit, QFileDialog
from PyQt5 import uic
import sys


class UI(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        uic.loadUi("GUI.ui", self)
        button = self.findChild(QPushButton, 'pushButton')
        button.clicked.connect(self.open)
        button2 = self.findChild(QPushButton,'pushButton')
        button2.clicked.connect(self.cleanPlate)   

def open(self):
    filename =QFileDialog.getOpenFileName(self, "Open files", "", "Only Support(*.jpg *.png *.xmp)")
    self.lineEdit.setText(filename[0])
    global userinput
    userinput = self.lineEdit.text()
```

** how to use clean plate fucntion ? **

```
def cleanPlate(self):
    gray_img = cv2.cvtColor(, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    bfilter = cv2.bilateralFilter(gray_img, 11, 17, 17)
    edged = cv2.Canny(bfilter, 30, 200)
    keypoints = cv2.findContours(edged.copy(), cv2.RETR_TREE, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
    contours = imutils.grab_contours(keypoints)
    contours = sorted(contours, key=cv2.contourArea, reverse=True)[:10]
    location = None
    for contour in contours:
        approx = cv2.approxPolyDP(contour, 10, True)
        if len(approx) == 4:
            location = approx
            break
    # Maskng plate
    mask = np.zeros(gray_img.shape, np.uint8)
    new_image = cv2.drawContours(mask, [location], 0,255, -1)
    (x,y) = np.where(mask==255)
    (x1, y1) = (np.min(x), np.min(y))
    (x2, y2) = (np.max(x), np.max(y))
    cropped_image = gray_img[x1:x2+1, y1:y2+1]
    text = tess.image_to_string(cropped_image, lang='eng')
    print("Number  Detected Plate Text : ",text)

app = QApplication([])
window = UI()
window.show()
app.exec_()
```

**I started a simple image processing project that finds the location of the license plate and extracts the text inside it and it works without any problems.
Now, to expand this project, I decided to design and integrate a simple graphical environment with the PiQT library with the code I wrote, but now I do not know how to use key 2 and give way to OpenCV.
Thank you for your help
Thanks**

Comment: please see [signals and slots](https://doc.qt.io/qtforpython/overviews/signalsandslots.html).

Comment: Can you please give some feedback to my answer?

Answer (score 1):

Assume we want to select an image file using PyQt5, read the image using OpenCV, execute `cleanPlate` with the loaded image, and display some result in the UI of PyQt5.

- Design a simple "Form" using Qt Designer.
  For example, the form has two buttons and a label (the label is used for showing an image).
- When "Open" button is pressed, read the image to `self.img` using OpenCV:

  ```
   filename = QFileDialog.getOpenFileName(self, "Open files", "", "Only Support(*.jpg *.png *.xmp)")
   self.img = cv2.imread(filename[0])
  ```
- When "Clean Plate" button is pressed, execute the algorithm using OpenCV.
  Use `self.img` as input image to the algorithm.
  Prepare the result to be shown in the UI using OpenCV.
  Convert the image from NumPy array to `QPixmap`, and update the `label` to show the image.
  Example:

  ```
   # Get the label for showing new_image in the UI.
   label = self.findChild(QLabel, 'newImageLabel')

   # Draw the contour on self.img (store the result in new NumPy array named "imgae")
   image = cv2.drawContours(self.img.copy(), [location], 0, (0, 255, 0), 4)

   # Resize image to fit to the dimensions of label (this is just an example - we may also choose to modify the label size).
   image = cv2.resize(image, [label.width(), label.height()], interpolation=cv2.INTER_AREA)

   # Convert new image color format to BGRA (assume Qt preferred color format is BGRA).
   image = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2BGRA)

   # Convert new_image from NumPy array to QPixmap (Format_ARGB32 applies BGRA color format).
   qimage = QImage(image, image.shape[1], image.shape[0], image.strides[0], QImage.Format_ARGB32)
   qpix = QPixmap(qimage)
   label.setPixmap(qpix)
  ```

---

Example for OpenCV result showed in the UI:
[image]

Sample Form in Qt Designer:
[image]

Sample input image (`plate1.jpg`):
[image]

---

Complete code sample:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
import imutils
import pytesseract as tess
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QWidget, QPushButton, QLineEdit, QFileDialog, QLabel
from PyQt5.QtGui import QImage, QPixmap
from PyQt5 import uic
import sys

tess.pytesseract.tesseract_cmd = r'C:\Program Files\Tesseract-OCR\tesseract.exe'  # I am using Windows

class UI(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        uic.loadUi("GUI.ui", self)
        button = self.findChild(QPushButton, 'openPushButton')
        button.clicked.connect(self.open)
        button2 = self.findChild(QPushButton,'cleanPlatePushButton')
        button2.clicked.connect(self.cleanPlate)
        self.img = None  # Initialize the image to None

    def open(self):
        filename = QFileDialog.getOpenFileName(self, "Open files", "", "Only Support(*.jpg *.png *.xmp)")
        #self.lineEdit.setText(filename[0])
        #global userinput
        #userinput = self.lineEdit.text()

        # Read the selected image from file into the NumPy array self.img (OpenCV applies BGR pixel format).
        self.img = cv2.imread(filename[0])


    def cleanPlate(self):
        # Use self.img as input to the "Clean Plate" algorithm
        gray_img = cv2.cvtColor(self.img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
        bfilter = cv2.bilateralFilter(gray_img, 11, 17, 17)
        edged = cv2.Canny(bfilter, 30, 200)
        keypoints = cv2.findContours(edged.copy(), cv2.RETR_TREE, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
        contours = imutils.grab_contours(keypoints)
        contours = sorted(contours, key=cv2.contourArea, reverse=True)[:10]
        location = None
        for contour in contours:
            approx = cv2.approxPolyDP(contour, 10, True)
            if len(approx) == 4:
                location = approx
                break
        # Maskng plate
        mask = np.zeros(gray_img.shape, np.uint8)
        new_image = cv2.drawContours(mask, [location], 0, 255, -1)
        (x,y) = np.where(mask==255)
        (x1, y1) = (np.min(x), np.min(y))
        (x2, y2) = (np.max(x), np.max(y))
        cropped_image = gray_img[x1:x2+1, y1:y2+1]
        text = tess.image_to_string(cropped_image, lang='eng')
        print("Number  Detected Plate Text : ",text)

        # Get the label for showing new_image in the UI.
        label = self.findChild(QLabel, 'newImageLabel')

        # Draw the contour on self.img (store the result in new NumPy array named "imgae")
        image = cv2.drawContours(self.img.copy(), [location], 0, (0, 255, 0), 4)

        # Resize image to fit to the dimensions of label (this is just an example - we may also choose to modify the label size).
        image = cv2.resize(image, [label.width(), label.height()], interpolation=cv2.INTER_AREA)

        # Convert new image color format to BGRA (assume Qt preferred color format is BGRA).
        image = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2BGRA)

        # https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34232632/convert-python-opencv-image-numpy-array-to-pyqt-qpixmap-image
        # Convert new_image from NumPy array to QPixmap (Format_ARGB32 applies BGRA color format).
        qimage = QImage(image, image.shape[1], image.shape[0], image.strides[0], QImage.Format_ARGB32)
        qpix = QPixmap(qimage)
        label.setPixmap(qpix)


app = QApplication([])
window = UI()
window.show()
app.exec_()
```

---

Content of `GUI.ui` XML file:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ui version="4.0">
 <class>Form</class>
 <widget class="QWidget" name="Form">
  <property name="geometry">
   <rect>
    <x>0</x>
    <y>0</y>
    <width>450</width>
    <height>294</height>
   </rect>
  </property>
  <property name="windowTitle">
   <string>Form</string>
  </property>
  <widget class="QPushButton" name="openPushButton">
   <property name="geometry">
    <rect>
     <x>10</x>
     <y>10</y>
     <width>81</width>
     <height>31</height>
    </rect>
   </property>
   <property name="text">
    <string>Open</string>
   </property>
  </widget>
  <widget class="QPushButton" name="cleanPlatePushButton">
   <property name="geometry">
    <rect>
     <x>10</x>
     <y>50</y>
     <width>81</width>
     <height>31</height>
    </rect>
   </property>
   <property name="text">
    <string>Clean Plate</string>
   </property>
  </widget>
  <widget class="QLabel" name="newImageLabel">
   <property name="geometry">
    <rect>
     <x>110</x>
     <y>20</y>
     <width>320</width>
     <height>240</height>
    </rect>
   </property>
   <property name="text">
    <string/>
   </property>
  </widget>
 </widget>
 <resources/>
 <connections/>
</ui>
```